# Parsing a JSON key/value to a bool

Tags: php, json

I am working with this JSON data:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Expires" : 0
    }
}
```

And I want to convert *whatever* is in the "Expires" key to a bool value.

Whether it is `"true"`,`"false"`, `"no"`, `"yes"`, `0`, `1`, `true`, `false`

First I check if the value even exists.

```
 //DEFAULT
    $EXPIRES = false;

     if(array_key_exists('Expires', $DATA)) {

                if (isset( $DATA[ 'Expires' ] )) {
                    $EXPIRES = strtolower( clean_input( $DATA[ 'Expires' ] ) );
                    if (checkIfBoolean( $EXPIRES )) {
 //OK IT IS A BOOLEAN VALUE SET IT
                        $EXPIRES = filter_var(    $EXPIRES, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
                    } else {
                        return array( "Code" => 0, "Error" => "Expires is not a boolean [0, 1]." );
                    }
                }
        }

//CAN'T TRUST THE USER, CLEAN THEIR INPUT
 function clean_input ( $data ) {
        $data = trim( $data );
        $data = stripslashes( $data );
        $data = htmlspecialchars( $data );

        return $data;
    }

//CHECK IF BOOLEAN

  function checkIfBoolean ( $string ) {
        $string = strtolower( $string );

        return ( in_array( $string, array( "true", "false", "1", "0", "yes", "no"), true ) );

    }
```

But when I check the variable

```
echo 'Expires: ' . $EXPIRES ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

It always returns `true`.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You're setting it to 'YES' if it's any of those values. So even it it's "false", "0" or "no", you still set it to 'YES'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is the here `'Expires: '. $EXPIRES ? 'YES' : 'NO';` you are concatenating these two `'Expires: '. $EXPIRES` so it will always return `YES`

**Change this to:**

```
echo 'Expires: '. $EXPIRES ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

**This:**

```
if($EXPIRES===true)
{
    echo 'Expires: '.$EXPIRES;
}
```